# How can i connect custom HTML form with wordpress email adress

Tags: wordpress, forms, email

I am using Wordpress and framework Gantry 5, I have custom html form added via JS as an innerHTML added to existing container.

I want this form values be submitted to email adress defined in WordPress administration settings. Is there any way i can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends from the form action, if your form action call a function inside your wordpress (for example in function.php) you can pick the email address

`get_option('admin_email')`

and use it to send the post data.

If the form action call a function external to you wordpress you can add the email as an hidden field in your form

```
<input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo get_option('admin_email'); ?>">
```

and get the value in the $_POST object.

Because you form is added by javascript you can add the hidden field by javascript before the form submit maybe using jquery (you also can do this in vanilla js).
If you print the script directly inline with php

```
$("#yourFormID").submit( function(eventObj) {
      $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
          .attr("name", "email")
          .attr("value", "<?php echo get_option('admin_email'); ?>" )
          .appendTo("#form");
      return true;
  });
```

If you put the script in js file you can print the hidden field outside with php and then pick the value with jquery (or also vanilla)

```
<input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo get_option('admin_email'); ?>">
```

```
$("#yourFormID").submit( function(eventObj) {
      $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
          .attr("name", "email")
          .attr("value", $('#email').val() )
          .appendTo("#form");
      return true;
  });
```